# JPA Update Parent even Child gets update error

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, entitymanager, openjpa

I have parent table (Order) and child table (OrderDetail)
I update my parent table first then update child table. because of some data issue my child table update is getting PRIMARY KEY constraint error and somehow it rollbacks my parent table also. I still want to continue with other child record even if my child gets error for one of its record.

Looks like Entity Manager does rollback to parent also when I get error for child. I actually want to avoid this.

So my requirement is even though one of the child gets an error, my parent and other child should be continue with update. which is i am handling in java but entity manager is doing it's own stuff

```
Order.java
// bi-directional many-to-one association to OrderDetail
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<OrderDetail> orderDetails;

OrderDetail.java
// bi-directional many-to-one association to Order
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
private Order order;
```

Here I am using separate native query for both parent and child with **em.createQuery**, **executeUpdate** and entity manager is same.

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
EntityManager em = DbConnectionFactory.INSTANCE.getEntityManagerSql();

em.getTransaction().begin();
updateOrderMaster(em, order);

List<Item> itmList = order.getOrderItems();
if (itmList != null && !itmList.isEmpty()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < itmList.size(); i++) {
    Item itm = itmList.get(i);
    try {
         updateOrderItems(em, order, itm);
    } catch (DetailOrderSaveException detailException) {
         LOGGER.debug("DetailOrderSaveException...");
         continue;
    }                
  }
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

update master method

```
private void updateOrderMaster(EntityManager em, Order order) {
try {

  em.createQuery("update Order o set o.orderStatus= :oStatus " + "where o.orderId = :oId")
          .setParameter("oStatus", FINAL)
          .setParameter("oId", Integer.parseInt(order.getOrderId())).executeUpdate();

} catch (Exception ex) {

}
}
```

update child method

```
private void updateOrderItems(EntityManager em, Order order, Item itm)
  throws DetailOrderSaveException {
try {

  em
      .createQuery("update OrderDetail o set o.id.statusCode= :sCode1 where o.id.formId = :fId "
          + "and o.id.orderId = :oId and o.id.statusCode = :sCode2")
      .setParameter("sCode1", Short.parseShort(itm.getStatus()))
      .setParameter("fId", Integer.parseInt(itm.getFormId()))
      .setParameter("oId", Integer.parseInt(supplyOrder.getOrderId()))
      .setParameter("sCode2", Short.parseShort(itm.getPreviousStatus())).executeUpdate();

} catch (Exception ex) {
  throw new DetailOrderSaveException(exception);
}
}
```

Comment: *my parent and other child should be continue with update. which is i am handling in java* How exactly? You will need to post the relevant code if you want an answer as to why it is not working.

Comment: updated code, please let me know if anything else

Comment: Sorry but you have 1 transaction wrapping the entire operation so all the updates will succeed or rollback together. You will need to look at doing each update in its own transaction.